# Legendre Symbols Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Calculate $\left(\frac{1}{73}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{73}\right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{72}{73}\right)$.

I tried to find a pattern and got $1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,\ldots$ so I didn't see much of one. I am not sure what to do to solve this.

Comment: How many quadratic residues are there modulo an odd prime $p$?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_Quadratic_Residues_of_a_Prime

Comment: Legendre symbol modulo a prime is multiplicative. Can you see how this implies that exactly half of those numbers are quadratic non-residues?

Comment: In a given complete set of residues modulo an odd prime, there are always the same number of quadratic residues and non-residues...

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $73$ is prime, $x^2\equiv a\pmod{73}$ will have two or zero solutions